# $\mathbb Z^2\subset G$ implies $F\not \stackrel{f.i.}{\subset} G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ a finitely generated group which has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$. I need to show that $G$ cannot have a free group $F$ as a finite index subgroup.

So far I noticed that then $\mathbb Z^2 \cap F$ has finite index in $\mathbb Z^2$. But how do I proceed from here??

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z^2\cap F$ is a non-cyclic abelian subgroup of $F$

Comment: hm...lets give it a try: Every subgroup of $F$ is free. But the only free group which is abelian, is $\mathbb Z$. But this group is cyclic. @HagenvonEitzen Is that right?

Comment: Why is the intersection non-cyclic?

Comment: @stacky is $\mathbb{Z}$ finite index in $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: using the standard embedding, surely not

Comment: @stacky if the intersection were cyclic, then it should follow that $F$ is not finite index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show that (a) if $G$ has a free subgroup of finite index, then every subgroup of $G$ has a free subgroup of finite index. (b) $\mathbf{Z}^2$ has no free subgroup of finite index.

(Remark: this relies on the classical result that subgroups of free groups are free; nevertheless here it is enough to check that every **abelian** subgroup of a free group is free [and hence cyclic]; this latter fact is easier: in a free group, every nontrivial element has an infinite cyclic centralizer.)

Comment: "every abelian subgroup of a free group is free [and hence cyclic]" I dont understand this. Doesn't cyclic just mean that the group is genereated by one element? There are certainly free groups which cannot be genereted by one element.

Comment: @stacky you possibly didn't notice the word "abelian" in my sentence, although it was boldfaced...

Comment: how can i show b?

Comment: so you meant that the subgroup if free abelian?

Comment: I guess you are just saying that every subgroup of a free group is free and thus if we require the subgroup to be also abelian, then it has to be $\mathbb Z$. At least thats how I would argue.

Comment: More precisely it has to be isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$ or $\{1\}$. Yes it's a reformulation of what I said.

Comment: How can I show that $Z^2$ does not admit a free subgroup of finite index?

Comment: Show that every subgroup of finite index in $Z^2$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $Z^2$.